# how to make a collapsible sidebar in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to implement collapse functionality to my sidebar so that when it closes only icons in menubar should be visible.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EISEp.png)

Sidebar Code:

```
return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <div className="sidebarWrapper">
        <div className="sidebarMenu">
          <ul className="sidebarList">

            <li className="mb-3">
              
              <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Search Modules" variant="outlined" size="small" onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
              />
             
            </li>

            {
            search ?  searchedMenu.map((val) => (
              <NavLink to={val.routing} className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? 'link-active' : 'link')}>
              <li className="sidebarListItem">
                {val.icon} &nbsp;&nbsp;{val.name}
              </li>
            </NavLink>
            )): 
            menuItems.map((val) => (
            <NavLink to={val.routing} className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? 'link-active' : 'link')}>
            <li className="sidebarListItem">
              {val.icon} &nbsp;&nbsp;{val.name}
            </li>
          </NavLink>
          ))

            }

          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve that, and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add state of Collapsed in the sidebar component.

Sidebar.jsx

```
const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(false);

return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <div className="sidebarWrapper">
        <div className="sidebarMenu">
          <ul className={`sidebarList ${collapsed && 'collapsed'}`}>

            <li className="mb-3">
              {collapsed ? <>Search Icon</> : <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Search Modules" variant="outlined" size="small" onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
              />}

             
            </li>

            {
            search ?  searchedMenu.map((val) => (
              <NavLink to={val.routing} className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? 'link-active' : 'link')}>
              <li className="sidebarListItem">
                {val.icon} {!collapsed && <>&nbsp;&nbsp;{val.name}</>}
              </li>
            </NavLink>
            )): 
            menuItems.map((val) => (
            <NavLink to={val.routing} className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? 'link-active' : 'link')}>
            <li className="sidebarListItem">
              {val.icon} {!collapsed && <>&nbsp;&nbsp;{val.name}</>}
            </li>
          </NavLink>
          ))

            }

          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  )
```

I have added `collapsed` class when collapsed. Collapsed class should do have styling for wrapping the sidebar in width and hide overflow the sidebar.

```
.collapsed {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 50px; // To show only icon
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```ts
const [isCollapsed, setIsCollapsed] = useState(false);

return(
  <button onClick={() => setIsCollapsed(!isCollapsed)} /> // open/close menu component
  ...
  <ul className="sidebarList">
    <li>
      <Icon />
      {!isCollapsed && <span>Name</span>} // only show names if isCollapsed = false
    </li>
  </ul>
)
```